# HTML5 FileReader in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, opera, filereader

I am trying to read multiple local ogg audio files using the file reader api in opera 12 by converting them into data urls and storing them into an array which I intend to access later.

```
    function music(list)
    {
        var playlistlength=0;
        try
        {
           for (var temp=0; temp < list.files.length; temp++)
           {
             f[playlistlength][0] = list.files.item(temp).name;
             var freader = new FileReader();
             freader.onload = function(frevent){
                                      f[playlistlength][1]=frevent.target.result;
                                               };
             freader.readAsDataURL(list.files[temp]);
             playlistlength++;
           }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
           alert("Error");
        }
     }
```

However upon inspection in the debugger, in the for loop , no statement is executed and it jumps to the catch block, unable to figure it out.Can someone explain why its happening and any alternatives if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use `alert(e);` instead of `alert("Error");`, what message do you get?

Comment: thanks but alert is not the culprit here, ricola3d sorted it out.

Comment: I know but if you'd answer me it would be easier for us to debug. Please don't ignore other users' questions next time.

Answer (score 0):

This works on jsFiddle. I made it from your code, is your use of it similar ?

HTML :

```
   ​<input type="file" id="browser"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript :

```
   function music(list)
   {
     var playlistlength=0;
      var f = new Array();
     try
     {
       for (var temp=0; temp < list.files.length; temp++)
       {
         var music = new Array();
         music[0] = list.files.item(temp).name;
         var freader = new FileReader();
         freader.onload = function(frevent){
           music[1]=this.result;
           f.push(music);
           alert(f);
         };
         freader.readAsDataURL(list.files[temp]);
         playlistlength++;
       }
       alert(f);
     }
     catch(e)
     {
        alert(e);
     }
   }

   function FileSelectHandler(e) {
     var list = e.target || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
     music(list);
   }

   document.getElementById("browser").onchange = FileSelectHandler;
```

Why it didn't work ?

- First you tried to set a value in f[playlistlength][1], because of
  the onload function asynchronously executing after the
  playlistlength++. It crashed because this reference didn't exist.
- f was probably wrong declared ​

Comment: thanks for helping me out , turns out that the first reason you specified about the asynchronous onload event is the culprit, did some research on it and learnt that the playlistlength reaches the end of array 'f' before the data urls are actually loaded into it and hence it crashes. Tried your code , but there are dependencies of other functions in my code and instead of playing the audio files loaded this way, the data urls are displayed in opera, I can work on changing it , thanks, btw tried to use FileReaderSync but opera and IE10 do not seem to support it.